# Protect non-api (res.render) route with express-jwt token in Node.js

Tags: node.js, view, render, token, jwt

First of all, I have read all tutorials on protecting REST API routes with jwt (express-jwt & jsonwebtoken), and it works fine for that purpose.

This works fine:

```
app.use('/api', postApiRoute);
```

And this also works, somewhat, I mean.. it does verify the token when I use it to show a webpage with angular http request calls, but when you add `expressJwt({secret: secret.secretToken})`, you cannot just access `localhost:3000/api/post` anymore. The `expressJwt({secret: secret.secretToken})` is the problem here.

```
app.use('/api', expressJwt({secret: secret.secretToken}));
app.use('/api', userApiRoute);
```

What I really need is to **protect a non-json but html/text request** route with jwt like eg.:

```
app.get('/admin*', expressJwt({secret: secret.secretToken}), function(req, res){
    res.render('index', {
        //user: req.session.user, <- not sure how to do the equivalent, to extract the user json-object from the express-jwt token?
        js: js.renderTags(),
        css: css.renderTags()
    });
});
```

.. without having to make http requests in angular/js, but using express' render function.

I need to do this since my application has 2 primary server routed views, so 1 where admin scripts are loaded from, and 1 where the frontend (theme) assets gets loaded.

I cant however get jwt/tokens to work with server rendered views, only json api requests.

The error i'm getting is: *"UnauthorizedError: No Authorization header was found"*

Couldn't find any information about (server rendered views protected with jwt, only serverside api requests and client side angular/ajax http requests) this, so I hope my question is clear, and that I do not have to fall back to using sessions again.

Comment: Hey, did you ever get anywhere with this? I'm also trying to muddle through this. It seems crazy that you can't protect simple GET routes. If know, I have a question here that I'll happily accept an answer on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822234/correct-way-to-protect-url-with-json-web-token-and-node-js-express/31822349#31822349

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but if you are talking about *entry* html routes (i.e., loaded directly by the browser and not by you angular app), then you simply have no way of instructing the browser as to how to set the authorization header (no without introducing some other redirect based auth flow).