# Correct way to protect URL with JSON web token and node.js/express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, authentication

I'm currently authorizing users with JSON web tokens using node.js and express with EJS as the view engine.

Using simple middleware in my server.js file:

```
app.use(function(request, response, next){
        var token = request.body.token || request.query.token || request.headers['x-access-token'];
        console.log(request.body);
        if(token){
        jwt.verify(token, app.get('superSecret'), function(err, decoded){
                   if(err){
                   response.json({"message": "Failed to authenticate user"});
                   }
                   else{
                   request.decoded = decoded;
                   next();
                   }
                   });
        }
        else{
        return response.status(403).json({"message":"No token was provided"});
        }
        });
```

and protected routes below it e.g:

```
app.post('/userlist', function(request, response) {
        response.json({some: json})
        });
```

What I can't understand or figure out is how to protect a GET route such as:

```
app.get('/userprofile', function(request, response) {
            response.render('pages/userprofile');
            });
```

If I make the request by some url directly `www.example.com/userprofile` access is denied, as there is no token included with the request.

If I make it via ajax:

```
$.ajax({
           type:"GET",
           url:"https://www.example.com/userprofile",
           headers:{"x-access-token": token },
           success: function(result, success){
           },
           error: function (result, error){
           }
       });
```

The response is not rendered but comes back in the result object. I've got my wires crossed somewhere here.

Answer (score 2):

A token needs to be passed in order to be used.  If the server doesn't have access to it, the server can't validate it.  So, you can pass the token in the path :

```
app.get('/userprofile/:token',function(request,response){
  console.log(request.params.token);
});
```

In the query string :

```
app.get('/userprofile',function(request,response){
  console.log(request.query.token);
});
```

Or as a cookie :

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser);
app.get('/userprofile',function(request,response){
  console.log(request.cookies.token);
});
```

Comment: I'm confused as to how I can do this when for example I have the token in local storage. How can I append this value to the request if it's a simple link in the header, i.e `<li><a href="/userprofile">Profile</a></li>`?

Comment: Sounds like cookies is going to be the way to go for you.  Have you considered using express-session?

Comment: Coming back to this, is it "bad practice" to use the token approach above, simply appending to the url?

Comment: I would look into express-session

Answer (score 0):

http response code should be sent, default is 200 as in your case `response.json({"message": "Failed to authenticate user"});`

try
`response.json(401, {"message": "Failed to authenticate user"});`